# How to correctly implement SPF record

Tags: dns-servers

I am currently using FreshBooks as my invoicing/accounting system. Freshbooks sends (or at least should send) automated invoices to clients when an invoice is created so they can pay. Unfortunately with clients who use Microsoft Exchange email servers they do not ever received the emails (i'm assuming because of their spam blockers). I contacted Freshbooks and they recommend adding an SPF record, but offer no support on it. Below is a screenshot of my DNS Made Easy (just a DNS host) SPF record section. Can you please let me know if it's implemented right?

Thanks![image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SPF needs to list all sources of email.

In addition to Freshbooks, you also need to list any other systems that also send email on behalf of your domain.

The SPF you have entered will permit email from:
a = a record for the domain
include = allows email from freshbooks

So right now, any email coming from the A record for your domain and Freshbooks will be permitted.

If you are sending email from other sources, then those IPs, records or includes will also be required.

You can use tools like:

http://www.spfwizard.net/

or

https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/spfwizard/

To help you build the correct SPF record.

Once you have your record setup, give the DNS time to update and then email Google & Yahoo accounts.   If you then review the headers of the emails, you can see if they mark your SPF as passing.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just got confirmation from one of my clients that automated emails are now going through. Freshbooks is the only app that is sending email on my behalf (I use Google Apps for email hosting, and they send fine). @jeffatrackaid

Comment: If you use google apps (Gmail) for email hosting. You will also need to include their info.  See https://support.google.com/a/answer/178723?hl=en&ref_topic=2759192